# Print number if it matches the sum and product with Shell Script

Tags: shell, if-statement, while-loop, sum, product

I am having syntax error with my script, I'm sure i have the logic set but seem to be having issues with the formatting of the script.

The expected workflow is

if n = ((sum) + (product)) then print n and n++ repeat.
else n++ repeat.

```
    #!/bin/bash
function sum() {
    local n=$1
    local res=0
    while [ $n -gt 0 ]
    do
        local sdigit=$(( $n % 10 ))
        local n=$(( $n / 10 ))
        local res=$(( $res + $sdigit ))
    done
    echo $res
}

function prod() {
    len=$(echo $1 | wc -c)
    len=$(( $len - 1 ))

    res=1

    for (( i=1; i <= $len; i++ )) 
    do 
         res=$(($res * $(echo $1 | cut -c $i) )) 
    done 
    echo $res
}

#####################################################

n=0
my_prod=$(prod $n)
my_sum=$(sum $n)

while [ $n -le 10 ];
do
    if (( n == $((my_prod + my_sum)) ))
    then
        echo "$n"
        n++
    break
    else
        n++
    fi
done
```

Comment: Have you run your code through [**Shellcheck.net**](http://www.shellcheck.net/)? `if [ $n -eq $((my_prod + my_sum)) ]` ?? or `if (( n == $((my_prod + my_sum)) ))` ??

Comment: Thanks! I did not know about that site, definitely bookmarked. ive fixed a couple things and will update the post

Comment: I have now run the entire script through shellcheck and only suggestions are shown now, no errors.

Answer (score 1):

`((expression))` will perform the arithmetic operation but *will not return anything*, so this is invalid:

```
# INVALID SYNTAX
if [ $n = (($my_prod + $my_sum)) ]
```

Also, `=` will compare strings, so `01 = 1` returns false. Prefer `==` or `-eq`. All in all this is what you want:

```
if [ $n -eq $(($my_prod + $my_sum)) ]
```

(I have not checked the other lines, but yeah shellcheck is your friend.)

Edit: borrowed from comments, this is also good:

```
if (( n == $((my_prod + my_sum)) ))
```

Answer (score 1):

Continuing from my comments, after you have run though shell check and get no errors, you still must fix your `n++`, which by itself is an error. To increment `n` use `((n++))`.

You are also not updating `my_prod` and `my_sum` on each iteration of the `while` loop. Your comparison of `n == $((my_prod + my_sum))` is suspect. I suspect you are after `if ((my_prod == my_sum))`. That would allow you to compare whether the product and sum of the digits of say `22` are equal (e.g. `2+2 = 2*2`). Correcting those will allows your code make the comparisons that I think you are after, e.g.

```
n=0

while [ $n -le 30 ];
do
    my_prod=$(prod $n)
    my_sum=$(sum $n)
    printf "n(%2d) - prod: %3d, sum: %3d" "$n" "$my_prod" "$my_sum" 

    if ((my_prod == my_sum))
    then
        # echo "$n -> product ($my_prod) == sum ($my_sum)"
        printf " -> (%3d == %3d)" "$my_prod" "$my_sum" 
    fi
    printf "\n"

    ((n++))
done
```

You can clean up `prod` and `sum` similar to the following. **Note** to avoid calling the utilities within a loop, (e.g. `cut`, etc..) which would spawn separate sub-processes, you can simply use the `mod, divide by 10` logic to decompose the numbers in both `prod()` and `sum()`, e.g.

```
sum() {
    local len=${#1}
    local res=0
    local n=$1
    local res=0

    while [ $n -gt 0 ]
    do
        local sdigit=$(( n % 10 ))
        local n=$(( n / 10 ))
        local res=$(( res + sdigit ))
    done

    echo $res
}

prod() {
    local len=${#1}
    local res=1
    local n=$1

    while [ $n -gt 0 ]
    do
        local sdigit=$(( n % 10 ))
        local n=$(( n / 10 ))
        local res=$(( res * sdigit ))
    done

    echo $res
}
```

**Note:** if using a shell like bash that supports *string indexes*, you can further reduce `prod()` and `sum()` to:

```
sum() {
    [ -z "$1" ] && {
        echo 0
        return 1
    }
    echo $(($1 + $1))
}

prod() {
    [ -z "$1" ] && {
        echo 0
        return 1
    }
    echo $(($1 * $1))
}
```

Putting those pieces together, you could do something similar to the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

sum() {
    local len=${#1}
    local res=0
    local n=$1
    local res=0

    while [ $n -gt 0 ]
    do
        local sdigit=$(( n % 10 ))
        local n=$(( n / 10 ))
        local res=$(( res + sdigit ))
    done

    echo $res
}

prod() {
    local len=${#1}
    local res=1
    local n=$1

    while [ $n -gt 0 ]
    do
        local sdigit=$(( n % 10 ))
        local n=$(( n / 10 ))
        local res=$(( res * sdigit ))
    done

    echo $res
}

n=0

while [ $n -le 30 ];
do
    my_prod=$(prod $n)
    my_sum=$(sum $n)
    printf "n(%2d) - prod: %3d, sum: %3d" "$n" "$my_prod" "$my_sum" 

    if ((my_prod == my_sum))
    then
        printf " -> (%3d == %3d)" "$my_prod" "$my_sum" 
    fi
    printf "\n"

    ((n++))
done
```

**Example Use/Output**

Looking for those products and sums of the decomposed numbers between `0-30` you would find:

```
$ bash prodsum.sh
n( 0) - prod:   0, sum:   0 -> (  0 ==   0)
n( 1) - prod:   1, sum:   1 -> (  1 ==   1)
n( 2) - prod:   2, sum:   2 -> (  2 ==   2)
n( 3) - prod:   3, sum:   3 -> (  3 ==   3)
n( 4) - prod:   4, sum:   4 -> (  4 ==   4)
n( 5) - prod:   5, sum:   5 -> (  5 ==   5)
n( 6) - prod:   6, sum:   6 -> (  6 ==   6)
n( 7) - prod:   7, sum:   7 -> (  7 ==   7)
n( 8) - prod:   8, sum:   8 -> (  8 ==   8)
n( 9) - prod:   9, sum:   9 -> (  9 ==   9)
n(10) - prod:   0, sum:   1
n(11) - prod:   1, sum:   2
n(12) - prod:   2, sum:   3
n(13) - prod:   3, sum:   4
n(14) - prod:   4, sum:   5
n(15) - prod:   5, sum:   6
n(16) - prod:   6, sum:   7
n(17) - prod:   7, sum:   8
n(18) - prod:   8, sum:   9
n(19) - prod:   9, sum:  10
n(20) - prod:   0, sum:   2
n(21) - prod:   2, sum:   3
n(22) - prod:   4, sum:   4 -> (  4 ==   4)
n(23) - prod:   6, sum:   5
n(24) - prod:   8, sum:   6
n(25) - prod:  10, sum:   7
n(26) - prod:  12, sum:   8
n(27) - prod:  14, sum:   9
n(28) - prod:  16, sum:  10
n(29) - prod:  18, sum:  11
n(30) - prod:   0, sum:   3
```

If I misunderstood the goal of your code, drop a comment and help clarify what you are trying to achieve. After thinking about what you were doing, this edit was prompted.

**Example Use/Output with** `if ((n == $((my_prod + my_sum))))`

If you are actually looking for the equality where `n` is equal to the *product* plus *sum* of the decomposed numbers, then adjusting the output formatting, your only matches would be:

```
$ bash prodsum.sh
...
n(19) - prod:   9, sum:  10  (19 =  9 + 10)
...
n(29) - prod:  18, sum:  11  (29 = 18 + 11)
```

Comment: Thank you very much David, This is exactly what I was trying to achieve, I have added added (()) to my variable increment as I understand that is required to do math operations. I appreciate your help, you are right with your second example, I would like to print ONLY where n = (prod+sum).

Comment: Glad I could help. It took a while to 'snap' to what you were actually trying do. Once the light-bulb winked on, it made sense. Both POSIX shell (and the more advanced shells like bash) are very capable scripting languages. Arrays and string indexing in bash/zsh, etc.. will spoil you, but you can still accomplish the same thing in plain-old shell (it just takes a few more lines...)